# How do I create a StorageController in Node js for Azure File Sync?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, azure-blob-storage, azure-files

If i wish to create a StorageController to generate the SAS tokens inorder to make the Azure File Syncing work with Xamarin forms, is that possible ? All the documentation that I have seen only mention a way to do it in ASP.NET.

Reference :
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/file-management-with-azure-mobile-apps/

It seems I can create a SAS token in Node js, but how do I tie it up the /table endpoint ?
http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is significant work involved in creating the equivalent of a StorageController for the Node.js backend. You could create a simple custom API endpoint that generates SAS tokens and consume those from your client application, i.e. interacting directly with Azure Storage rather than using the file sync plugin for Azure Mobile Apps.

Comment: Hi Dale,
Thanks for the response. I can create a custom node js API endpoint for SAS tokens but what about the following two endpoints ? 
// Get the files associated with this record
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("tables/TableName/{id}/MobileServiceFiles")]
        
        [HttpDelete]
        [Route("tables/TableName/{id}/MobileServiceFiles/{name}")]
Aren't these required for IMobileServiceSyncTable.PushFileChangesAsync() to work?

Comment: Yes, precisely. As I said, there is a significant amount of work involved in creating the equivalent of a StorageController in Node.js.